# Get email in another model after user is created in django

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in django. When admin creates a user, I am trying to save some fields in `EmailAddress` model.But for some reason the `email` field is always blank. Is there any way I can update the instance with email in `UserProfile` or `EmailAddress` model.

models.py looks like this

```
User._meta.get_field('email').blank = False
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True


class EmailAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, related_name ='address')
    email = models.EmailField()
    verified = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('verified'), default=True)
    primary = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('primary'), default=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'account_emailaddress'


class UserProfile(models.Model, HashedPk):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, related_name ='profile')
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=False, default="")
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default="")
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField( blank=True, null=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        EmailAddress.objects.create(user=instance)
```

forms.py looks like this --

```
class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(label=_("Phone (Please state your country code eg. +44)"))
    organisation = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    captcha = ReCaptchaField(attrs={'theme' : 'clean'})


    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        up = user.profile
        up.phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        up.organisation = self.cleaned_data['organisation']
        user.save()
        up.save()
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In your EmailAddress model shouldn't you have an email field?

Comment: Sorry I have updated the model. But I get a blank value.

Comment: Can you show your views.py? Where are you calling signup for the form?

Comment: @Pblove In views.py there is no calling for signup form. Actually I have used django-allauth app. I think that's the problem. There is settings -- `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = "general.forms.SignUpForm"`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the allauth app but show me the views.py that deals with the form and I can take a look :)

Comment: There is nothing in views.py which deals with the signup form. The database insertion of user and userprofile is happening in forms.py

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. It needs to be

```
EmailAddress.objects.create(user=instance, email=instance.email)
```